# Сохранение массива структур в бинарном режиме C++

Tags: c++

При попытки сохранить массив структур TRAIN - station в файл в бинарном режиме выдаётся ошибка

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type
      'const std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>
      >::char_type *' (aka 'const char *') with an lvalue of type
      'TRAIN [3]'
```

Код сохранения в файл

```
ofstream out("data.txt",ios::binary);
out.write(station,sizeof(TRAIN)*n);
out.close();
```

Сама структура

```
const int L = 11;
struct TRAIN
{
    char NAZV[L];
    char NUMB[L];
    char DATE[L];
    char TIME[L]; 
};
```

Как я понял нужно поправить sizeof, но подскажите как именно, без помощи не смог разобраться.

Comment: `out.write((char*)station,sizeof(TRAIN)*n);` — надеюсь, `station` — это массив из `n` элементов `TRAIN`?

Comment: да, TRAIN station[n] = {};

Comment: ```passing argument to parameter '__s' here
write(const char_type* __s, streamsize __n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решилось добавление `(char*)&` перед station:

```
ofstream out("data.txt",ios::binary);
out.write((char*)&station,sizeof(TRAIN)*n);
out.close();
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ideone.com/ky0yuc — `out.write((char*)station,sizeof(TRAIN)*n);` достаточно, никакого `&` не требуется.